# Android - Puzzle Piece

Tags: android, puzzle

I'm trying to create a jigsaw puzzle app for Android. I am fairly far into the coding, and I am kind of stuck with one issue.

I need a way to change a Bitmap into a bunch of puzzle pieces. My current code simply cuts the image into rectangles, and it works pretty well, but now I need a way to create more complex piece shapes.

I had a couple of ideas:

- Use a separate bitmap file that contains only black and white pixels, and use that to cut up the picture. I thought this was a pretty good plan, until I went to code it. I really had no idea how to do it.
- Use a `Path` object to create the border. This would probably work, except I'm not sure how to keep track of the sides so that the pieces connect with each other.

Any ideas? I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Path` and/or `Region` to set a clip for your `Canvas` when drawing a `Bitmap`.

Take a look at [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Clipping.html). Here are some ways of clipping your drawing to any shape.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that example before. So is a Region basically the inside portion of a Path?

Comment: Well, I think `Region` is a region. It can be obtained in different ways. With paths or by combining some other regions using boolean operations: union, intersection and others. I think, given example is more descriptive than me. :)

Comment: Oh sorry Guys,... In the above answer, "Take a look at this example. Here are some ways of clipping your drawing to any shape."    Can you please mention the name of "this Example" , as samples are now moved from developer site & I am really in need of the same kind of code. Thank you.!!!

Comment: All examples could be found locally in your SDK directory: `<sdk>/samples/android-<version>/` and this example is in `<sdk>/samples/android-<version>/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Clipping.java`

Answer (score 0):

You could try making squares or rectangles fitted inside complex figures that can still be pieced toguether, when there's a match, the full rectangle covers the space. Imagine it like a  9 patch, when two sides match, you show the border rectangle.

Comment: But for that, wouldn't the shapes have to be orthagonal (90 degree corners)? So I wouldn't have any rounded connections?

Comment: no, i'll make a picture for you, find some online tool to make drawings and i'll make it.

Comment: If you guys have any code on what you did in the end or further info, AT ALL, I would be SOOOOO grateful, thanks, johnaashmore@AnAustralian.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a explicit solution but I wonder if it would be possible to use bezier curves or paths to create lines along x and y , in conjunction with a parameter(fed with random value) to control the amount of deviation from a straight line and how much in a given distance ie; pixels/ per inch - this would be to create tongues on the pieces. Then use Region to extract the resulting shape at a given side of an intersection. Have the shape object get its center xy coordinate at instantiation and make it so that piece cannot be set if its current coordinate does not match the one it had when it was created.